# Need example of using boost::fusion::filter_if metafunction

Tags: c++, boost-fusion

Given a boost::fusion::vector type, I want to filter out all the non-ref members to get a new type. For example this would transform boost::fusion::vector into
boost::fusion::vector. I'm guessing the boost::fusion::filter_if meta function might be able to do this,
but there's no example of its use in the documentation. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, there is an example here under  **Print only pointers**: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/quick_start.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/transformation/filter_if.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at_c.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/make_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>

using namespace boost::fusion;

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    double b = 11.;
    vector<int, int&, double, double&> vec(1, a, 13., b);

    if(filter_if<boost::mpl::not_<boost::is_reference<boost::mpl::_>>>(vec) == make_vector(1, 13.))
      std::cout << "MATCH" << std::endl;
}
```